# How to totally fix the SSLcertverificationError when using pip?

Tags: pip

What happens when I try to install something (pytorch for example) with pip:

'''Could not fetch URL https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/pytorch/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytorch/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping'''

One way to temporarily avoid this is seting the Use a Proxy Server switch to Off in the Windows Manual Proxy Setup section, but later it will be set back to On automatically.

So what's wrong with the pip or windows? or this Error is related to my vpn?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason!

The reason why the Use a Proxy Server switch automatically changes is my V2rayN had been closed abnormally, so its process continuously changes my settings. To fix this, I just restart V2rayN in administrator mode and quit so that it will manage proxy settings properly.

As to the SSLError, it is because the Proxy switch is on. So after I fix the switch I can use pip to install things again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Set up a proxy in your CMD session.

For example:

```
set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:10809
set https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:10809
```

So that your cmd session can use proxy to execute binary like "pip" without configuring proxy outside the cmd.